# Drupal - Lightbox -> iframe node displaying entire website with views

Tags: drupal, iframe, view, lightbox

I am attempting to make a view that would list thumbnails of my projects, then when clicking them enlarge the photo using lightbox and list out some text and a link to the website.

I am not sure if there is a way I can just add text to the lightbox using views so right now I have it using a field for Lightbox2 iframe: thumb200wh->node page. Open my entire website again in the lightbox instead of just the node:

http://jeffkilroy.com/portfolio_boxes

Is there a way to just display the node from the views module or is there a way to just use an image but modify the description so that I can put text in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method I use is described here:
http://drupal.org/node/252260
scroll down to the section called:
**Opening node content in a lightbox**

Answer (score 0):

read README.txt of lightbox, HTML Content Support (for showing html page via popup iframe window).
So you image should link and have rel="lightframe" attribute. How to add this for image in Views?

You can use manual theming Views: click on Information (in Views edit), select image field, select appropriate theming file, copy content of this link, add put tpl file into your theme. So now you can control this field displaying by theming this field. All variables you will see in comments. Investigate it through devel.